# Should infinite loop condition variables always be declared as volatile?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, volatile, compiler-optimization

Consider, such type of code,

```
while( !cond )
 ;
```

If **cond** is not declared volatile, the compiler can optimize it by caching it in a register. In that case, the while loop will continue even after **cond** is set.

Now does that mean that any such kind of variable should always be declared **volatile**? Why aren't the compilers smart enough to realize that it should not cache such variables?

Comment: I was always under the impression that such caching would only be dangerous when working with hardware?

Comment: @Sparticus: If you have two processors, then you are working with extra hardware when you are working with threads.

Comment: This volatile requirement is actually a fearsome trap for the unwary!

Answer (score 10):

Why would it not cache the variable? You don't change it in the loop, so it's equivalent, in C's mind, to `while (true);`.

That is, unless your program is multithreaded, in which case the variable *can* be changed while the loop is running and doing nothing. However, the C language doesn't know anything about threads (and more generally, as Lundin remarked, about any functions that aren't called from `main` or from a function called in `main`, etc), so you have to use `volatile` by yourself to let C know that something is going on that it doesn't know about.

Comment: Or rather, C doesn't know about things happening in functions that aren't explicitly called from main(). This could be thread functions, interrupts or callback functions. In all such cases, the variables shared between main() and that external function need to be volatile, to prevent optimizer-related bugs.

Comment: And further, be aware that `volatile` does not work for this purpose in all C implementations. Marking `cond` volatile here is not guaranteed by the standard to be sufficient to prevent a data race on `cond`, if `cond` is accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't think it's a race that's the problem being discussed is it? (Or is my understanding of "race" wrong?)

Comment: @Seth: I'm not totally familiar with this part of the standard, but in C++11 and I think in C11 as well, IIRC a "data race" is the term for any multi-threaded access to an object that doesn't have enough sequencing to deserve defined behavior. If I've used the wrong term, and "data race" means something more specific, then I don't mean "data race" :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop this is C though, not C++11, which is thread-aware (one step closer to SkyNet). Also, while this code probably does have the setup for a race condition, it's trivial enough I think that just making `cond` `volatile` will work to get you out of the loop. I guess it's just a matter of wording, but yes I definitely agree with you, it won't protect against a race condition. But that's not really what we were trying to use it for.

Comment: I just mean that although `volatile` will in practice prevent any optimizer from replacing the loop with `while(true);` or caching in a register, it *doesn't* in practice ensure that the emitted code will read through any memory caches etc. Even non-coherent caches tend to be eventually consistent, just because the cache gets flushed/cleared by random events like re-scheduling, but this isn't to be relied on. C11 is thread-aware too, which is my claim to justification for using the term "data race" in relation to C!

Comment: @Steve and Seth, For x86, it won't introduce race conditions though, as x86 has proactive cache coherence.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: by all means edit the question to say, "does that mean that on x86 any such kind of variable..." ;-) Anyway, since you haven't stated the type of `cond` or the nature of the changes, I'm pretty sure that you still haven't done enough to avoid all possible races. If `cond` is a `volatile long long` on a 32-bit system, and one thread writes `0x1` "at the same time as" a second thread writes `(long long)0x1 << 32`, I'm not sure all compilers necessarily guarantee the order they write the words. So in principle even with coherent caches you could end up with `cond` still false.

Comment: The simple advice is (1) use locks or other synchronization primitives; (2) when that's too slow, read up for your specific implementation what you have to do to get well-defined lock-free memory access or use the guarantees in C11 for atomic types. Making things `volatile` might be a necessary part of that, but you really can't treat it as sufficient.

Comment: @SteveJessop would `cond` be false for every check, or just one (or a few until the variable was updated)? If it's only for a few checks (i.e. the loop runs one or two more times than it should), I think that's acceptable since I wouldn't think it needs to stop on the very next iteration.

Comment: When I first read this post, I knew this debate would appear (again). No, volatile cannot be used to create atomic access. No, volatile cannot be used in place of a mutex/semaphore. No, volatile will in most implementations not create a memory barrier access. All of this is however entirely off topic. The answer correctly states that volatile should be used to prevent dangerous optimizer bugs, which has _nothing_ to do with the other things I just mentioned.

Comment: @Seth: in the slightly bizarre situation I just described, if the two threads write the words in reverse order, and just so happen to interleave, then the object `cond` comes out of it with value `0` regardless of whether it's `volatile` or not. Lundin's right, though, none of this addresses the bug in the questioner's code that the questioner was asking about. It addresses a completely separate bug in the questioner's code...